# Yii2 convert an object with keys to an array of form 0,1,2,3,

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am using Yii2 AuthManager to get a persions permissions using

```
  return [

    "permissions"  => \Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissionsByUser(
                            Yii::$app->user->identity->id ),
      ]
```

The above returns data of the form

```
"permissions": {

     "permission1":{
       "type": "2",
       "name": "permission1",        
       },

        "permission2":{
          "type": "2",
           "name": "permission2",
         }

          ..................

     }
```

What i was looking for is an outpiut like this

```
"permissions": {
     0:{
       "type": "2",
       "name": "permission1",
       },
       1:{
          "type": "2",
           "name": "permission2",
         }

          ..................

     }
```

How do i convert the above to an array of values not with the keys to get the desired output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you get the result in $permissions

```
foreach ($permissions as $key => $value){

     $new_perm[] = $value;

}
```

in $new_perm you should obtain the result you need

Comment: But there's no point in looping over permissions, just simply use `array_values`.

Comment: downvoting an accepted (an working)  answer ..Without motivation action is a vile act ..

Comment: Well, i didn't downvoted, just pointed you that it's workaround.

Comment: @Yupik   .my comment . is not for you ... It's for people who enjoy giving negative votes without contributing to providing valuable suggestions to suggest better answers or to help OP find the solution ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return [
     "permissions"  => array_values(\Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissionsByUser(
                        Yii::$app->user->identity->id )),
  ];
```